# Node Js angular cli, ng serve error, socket closed

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular, websocket, angular-cli

hello i am trying to learn angular framework with a udemy course. by following the course i am trying to run the server so i can display things in node js cmd line . when i run ng serve to run the server i am getting this socket closed error. see below pic. i am running windows 10 64 bit acer laptop. i have bracket editor,sublime . i dont know if any of these is interfering

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the node version you are using v7.1.0.
Uninstall node and install a prior node version for example v6.9.1.
Install angular-cli again and then run your project again.

Comment: yup that was it. reinstalled to previous and it works now

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too, there is a new Node Version now (v7.2.0), I've updated, and it's working fine now.

Comment: Wesley, actually it is a bug fixed at v 7.2, so you're right about that

Answer (score 1):

If you're using windows, i suggest you:

install chocolatey here: https://chocolatey.org/install, so you can easily install packages like nodejs with the command line.

Open a command prompt in admin mode and finally do:

```
> choco upgrade nodejs.install
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this sounds silly, but try closing your terminal (all of them) then open up a new terminal and make sure you **DON'T RESIZE** the terminal window... then try it again.

could possibly be this same bug: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12887

Comment: sorry to hear that :(

Answer (score 0):

Try running `ng serve` using a different port:

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4201 --live-reload-port 49153
```